# Grant user write permissions on /var/www/html via www-data group

Tags: linux

I've setup a new web server, I have created a user 'webuser', and have added the user to the group 'www-data'. When I try to upload a file via SFTP to /var/www/html I get an `Permission Denied` error.

So far I've tried;

```
usermod -aG www-data webuser
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html
```

None of these have allowed write permission on `/var/www/html`

The details of the folder are:

```
drwxrwxr-x  9 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 10 10:00 html
```

Comment: 1. make sure you actually access the correct folder, that user might come out inside a jailroot inside the sftp server, so `/var/www/html` might get interpreted _relative_ to the users home folder. Check by comparing the folder contents you see via sftp.  2. are you certain that you try to upload into exactly that folder and not a subfolder? If it is a subfolder you need to take care to have permissions for all folders up to and including that folder. So check the file system hierarchy below `/var/www/html`.

Comment: I've just used SSH to login as that user, and it's allowed me to create a folder within /var/www/html I can also create a file via SSH. So it is maybe an issue with my SFTP client.

Comment: Have a try doind the same using a sftp client, the setup might actually differ, though that is a question of your server side configuration which only you ahve access to.

Comment: I can create files and folders, but it seems I am unable to modify existing files. Ah, I need to change the owner of the files to www-data. I have uploaded the files as root before I'd set the permissions. I've updated the owner of all sub folders and files, and it's working now.

Comment: Sounds like you did not set `www-data` as the _primary_ group of that user, but only as some group. That means that files created by that user are generated user his primary group (maybe `users`?) which is not what you want. Alternatively you can control that using "sticky bits" in the file system or the settings of the sftp server (depending on what server you use).